# Hibernate Full Text Search

Tags: hibernate, search, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I was just created a hibernate full text search using hibernate-search-4.1.1.Final.jar and all runtime dependencies.
There is no errors in this application.
But my Lucene query unsing the query DSL doesn't return any results.
I mean doesn't return any of rows in the table.
can any one please help me.

Main Search program
    This Java code is used to perform hibernate full text search.

```
   public class MainSearch {
                public static void main(String args[]) {
            Iterator iterator;
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            // FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();

            // create native Lucene query unsing the query DSL
            // alternatively you can write the Lucene query using the Lucene query
            // parser
            // or the Lucene programmatic API. The Hibernate Search DSL is
            // recommended though
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Book.class).get();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword()
                    .onFields("title", "subtitle", "authors.name").matching("cpp")
                    .createQuery();

            // wrap Lucene query in a org.hibernate.Query
            org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(
                    query, Book.class);

            // execute search

            List result = hibQuery.list();
            iterator = result.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            // Check list empty or not
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Linked list is empty");
            }

            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488094/hibernate-mssql-fulltext-search-via-contains
same problem solved

Answer (score 2):

You didn't included anything on the DB (in your code). If you did outside your code, you need to index the DB before being able to seach. To do that, execute this:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

And you don't need an open transaction to search stuff, so you can remove that `org.hibernate.Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();` line (and replace it with the `startAndWait()` one above)

Reference: http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#indexing (since Lucene doesn't know about your DBMS and vice-versa, Hibernate Search is the link between them and indexing your data is what makes it searchable by Lucene)