# Jpa Specification cannot call contains function

Tags: jpa, full-text-search, contains

I've an entities class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_PERSON")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName="p_person")
public class P_person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 255)
    private String firstName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.firstName = first_name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        P_person p_person = (P_person) o;

        if ( ! Objects.equals(id, p_person.id)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "P_person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", first_name='" + firstName + "'" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and metamodel

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(P_person.class)
public abstract class P_person_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<P_person, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<P_person, String> firstName;

}
```

repository class

```
public interface P_personRepository extends JpaRepository<P_person,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<P_person> {

}
```

and rest api function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person_query",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RolesAllowed(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<P_person>> person_query(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) throws URISyntaxException {
    Pageable pageable = PaginationUtil.generatePageRequest(offset, limit, direction, property);
    Page<P_person> page = p_personRepository.findAll(CustomSpecification.whereP_person_query(name), pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/person_query", offset, limit);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

in CustomSpecification I've function for generate Specification

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(P_person_.firstName), "%" + name + "%");

        }
    };
}
```

My problem start when I've to change from like to use contains function in MS-SQL

from

```
select * from P_PERSON where first_name like N'%John%'
```

to

```
select * from P_PERSON where  CONTAINS(first_name, N'John')
```

I've try several approach but it still failed

**first**

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(contains);

        }
    };
}
```

this one generate sql :

```
select count(p_person0_.id) as col_0_0_ from P_PERSON p_person0_ where CONTAINS(p_person0_.first_name, ?)=1
```

the database response error with Incorrect syntax near '='.

**second**

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return criteriaQuery.where(contains).getRestriction();

        }
    };
}
```

this one return antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: function (CONTAINS)
which generate sql :

```
select generatedAlias0 from com.amlo.aers.domain.P_person as generatedAlias0
where function('CONTAINS', generatedAlias0.firstName, :param0) order by generatedAlias0.id asc
```

**third** 
I change return class to Integer and hope it may work.

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Expression<Integer> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Integer.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(contains, 0);

        }
    };
}
```

it generate sql :

```
select count(p_person0_.id) as col_0_0_ from P_PERSON p_person0_ where CONTAINS(p_person0_.first_name, ?)>0
```

which return error org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near '>'.

**4th**

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Predicate contains = (Predicate) criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return contains;

        }
    };
}
```

still error
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.function.ParameterizedFunctionExpression cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate

**5th**

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.not(contains));

        }
    };
}
```

still return antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: function (CONTAINS)

**6th**
after read all resources I found.

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            criteriaQuery.where(contains);
            return null;

        }
    };
}
```

still return antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: function (CONTAINS)

"whereP_person_query" may easily replace with native query.
But my problem is there are some Specification which have many criteria combine.
So I create "whereP_person_query" to prove usage of full text search in this project.

Could it really done this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to get this working by following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488094/hibernate-mssql-fulltext-search-via-contains
it seems we have to trick the jpa to generate `CONTAINS(columnName, param) and 1=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3992
I try to apply it and this code work.

```
public static Specification<P_person> whereP_person_query(String name) {
    return new Specification<P_person>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.and(), criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name)));
        }
    };
}
```

but in the end I can't use it due to performance of multi contain function in one SQL.

So I wrote another class that create sql using containstable.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution would work, but you should remove calling `criteriaBuilder.isTrue(contains)` - it adds comparison to true into the SQL, therefore you get = 1 at the end of the generated SQL query.

**Solution** is either to change return type of your `toPredicate` method from Predicate to Expression:

```
    @Override
    public Expression toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
        return contains; // return

    }
```

**Or if you absolutely must** return Predicate (modification of the interface is not an option), you should convert the expression to predicate without adding sideeffects - using `criteriaBuilder.add` method instead of `isTrue` should be ok:

```
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<P_person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
        return criteriaBuilder.and(contains);

    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer  
but it'not working  
Both answer can not compile  
It make me curious why Predicate which extend from Expression<Boolean> can not cast to Expression<Boolean>  
  
critiriaBuilder.and must send two expression like this  
    Predicate and(Expression<Boolean> x, Expression<Boolean> y);

It can one or many only for predicate  
    Predicate and(Predicate... restrictions);

Comment: when I try 
'Expression<Boolean> contains = criteriaBuilder.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(P_person_.firstName), criteriaBuilder.literal(name));
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.literal(Boolean.TRUE), contains);'

It throw this error

unexpected AST node: : near line 1, column 86
                    [select generatedAlias0 from P_person as generatedAlias0 where ( :param0 ) and ( function('CONTAINS', generatedAlias0.firstName, :param1) )]

Comment: sorry for unreadable format.
I just know it use another markdown

Comment: Automatic conversion does not work, becauae you need to get `Predicate` from `Expression‘. It would work in the opposite direction.

Comment: From the API, I do not see a reason, why `and` should require at least 2 expressions, although it makes sense. I could not find another way to convert `Expression` to `Predicate`. Try asking another question for this.

Comment: don't seem to work anymore with spring boot 3