# Hibernate + MSSQL + Fulltext Search via Contains SQLFunctionTemplate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, full-text-search

I've setup a fulltext index on my customer table to be able to quickly search for customers via their info.

I had to create a custom hibernate dialect to simplify the mapping.
and do some funky stuff to get hibernate to work
[Hibernate + MSSQL + Fulltext Search via Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488094/hibernate-mssql-fulltext-search-via-contains)

My custom dialect has a function that looks like this

```
registerFunction("contains", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "CONTAINS(?1, ?2) AND 1"));
```

This makes it possible to do queries as follows

```
from Customer c where contains(c.name, :term) = true
```

My problem now is that to be able to return parial matches I need to quote the term and add a *

So the raw query would be

```
select * from customer c where CONTAINS(c.name, '"mycust*"');
```

I've tried wrapping the SQLFunctionTemplate with quotes and a star, and tried quoting at the call site, but neither work.

Any suggestions on how to create a sql function that does the raw query above?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Hibernates criteria API and sqlRestriction then you can pass any string to the query u want. E.g. searchValue=myCust* etc...

```
   Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" CONTAINS(name, ?)", searchValue, StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
```